# how to display errors on MAMP?

Tags: php, html, macos, error-handling, mamp

I have MAMP, and I don't know how to display errors on it,
when I have error on my php code it shows only blank pages,
i have searched on Google, and I saw that I have to change it to display_errors = on on all of the folders and versions...
and include this on my page:
error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', 'on');

Answer (score 4):

Stop your server.

Go to

```
Applications/Mamp/bin/php/phpVERSION/conf/php.ini
```

Set

```
error_reporting=E_ALL
display_errors=On
```

Start your server.

---

If this doesn't help - please post your phpInfo page.

Comment: looks like a type, but it should be: 

display_errors = On

Answer (score 0):

This is how I got mine to display error:

1. Open **MAMP**
2. Click on **Server** tab
3. Click on **PHP**
4. Under **Write**, check **All errors and warnings** and **Notices**
5. Under **To**, check **Display** and **Log**

Answer (score 0):

I am using MAMP with php version 7.0.6.

What I did was go to `MAMP\conf\phpVERSION` and open up the `php.ini` file there and change the `display_errors` value there to `display_errors = On`.
Once changed, restart your MAMP.