# PHP errors in a new MAMP

Tags: php, mamp

I download absolutely new, the last version of MAMP 3.5.

I go to phpInfo and it says the PHP version is 7.0.0 and Configuration File (`php.ini`) Path is: `/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php7.0.0/conf`.

I go to `php.ini` in that path and change errors to on: `display_errors = On`. I check that: `error_reporting  =  E_ALL`.

I Stop Servers and Start Servers. I reload the page in the browser. I check phpInfo and now `display_errors` is on.

I do not see the errors.

I have checked all the solutions in the web, just to name a few: 
[MAMP Config help, display PHP errors](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2297618/mamp-config-help-display-php-errors)
[Why MAMP doesn't display errors?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14581460/why-mamp-doesnt-display-errors)
[how to display errors on MAMP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21784871/how-to-display-errors-on-mamp)

I tried everything and I do not see PHP errors. What else can I do?

Comment: try checking whether you have mentioned error_reporting(0); somewhere in your source code.

Comment: Did you check "Log error: to screen' in MAMP -> tab "PHP"?

Comment: @ameenulla0007 I just have the most basic error: missing ";" <?php 
echo "An error" ?>

Comment: @Yurich: I do not understand. Where is that? In Mamp > Preferences > PHP I do not see that option 'Log error: to screen'

Comment: @Nrc [image](https://www.mamp.info/en/images/screenshots/en_multi-php.jpg) check this out at the bottom

Comment: @Yurich: I have Mamp, no Mamp Pro

Comment: What errors do you expect to be shown where?

Comment: @deceze I just have a simple file to test, for instance an echo without ";" echo "this is an error"

Comment: If that's the only thing in the file, **it's not an error.**

Comment: @deceze: I followed a tutorial and there it was detected: www.youtube.com/watch?v=lY165def6Jk  minute 4:26 But not me, I do not know why?

Comment: Again, if it's ***the only thing*** in the file, it's fine. *The last* statement in a file does not require to be terminated by `;`, it'll be implicitly terminated by the end of the file. Try it with a simpler and less ambiguous error, like `echo $someUndefinedVariable;`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Preface your PHP code with this.  It will force error display.

```
ini_set('display_errors', 'On');
error_reporting(E_ALL);
```

Also check your .ini files in the following locations:

> Applications/MAMP/bin/php/(PHP version)/conf/php.ini
>
> Applications/MAMP/conf/php/(PHP version)/conf/php.ini

They should both be set for:

```
display_errors = On
```

EDIT:  I should clarify this, as it may be a point of confusion:  You should **restart your MAMP server** when the changes are complete.

Comment: See my update.  You may need to edit an additional .ini file

Comment: I did it and I checkec again and I see no errors. (by the way, the second path I have it here: Applications/MAMP/conf/(PHP version)/php.ini

Comment: Did you restart your MAMP server?

Answer (score 0):

I changed my .ini files located as Bangkoian stated above. In *MAMP PRO 3.5* there is an additional or third .ini file that needs to be changed.

This file can only be accessed through the MAMP Pro **File menu** . I'm not sure where it actually is in the actual file structure.

Access the .ini by: **Command +4** or
**File > Edit Template > PHP > Version Your using**

Find around line 271:

```
error_reporting  =  MAMP_error_reporting_MAMP
```

and change to  **E_ALL**

```
error_reporting  =  E_ALL
```

under *error_reporting* look for *display_errors* and change:

```
display_errors = MAMP_display_errors_MAMP
```

and change to  **On**

```
display_errors = On
```

You'll end up needing to change these line in **3 Different places**

> Applications/MAMP/bin/php/(PHP version)/conf/php.ini
>   
> Applications/MAMP/conf/php/(PHP version)/conf/php.ini

and through MAMP Pro itself:
**Command +4** or
**File > Edit Template > PHP > Version Your using**

After the third method was added it worked as expected, I'm also using PHP 7. Make sure *Debugger Activate Xdebug* it checked under the PHP tab.